# How can I print current reads and writes to the filesystem on demand?

Tags: linux, filesystems, io

I am interested in getting statistics about filesystem reads and writes, specifically to an NFS mount.

I know there are many tools such as `iostat`, `nfsstat` and `inotifywait` but there are issues I have with each program.

I cannot use anything that would require me to walk the filesystem or explicitly mention file names due to the complexity of the hierarchy.

Is there a program that can do the following on demand?

1. show reads / writes
2. show path of read / write
3. show byte quantity

By on demand, I mean on execution time. Point (3) is not mandatory.

For example, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
$ magicIOprogram
read, 512, /path/to/file1
read, 256, /path/to/file2
write, 15, /path/to/file3
write, 10562, /path/to/file4
```

If there are ways to get this information using the aforementioned tools that I am unaware of, it would also be a adequate solution.

Comment: `iosnoop` from [`perf-tools`](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) does some of what you're asking for, but I imagine it won't work on NFS. (See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205147/how-do-i-check-which-files-are-written-by-an-application/205224#205224 for an example.) You could look at `tcpdump` and Wireshark, perhaps there's an NFS analyser which would give you the necessary information...

Comment: @StephenKitt doesn't seem like a bad idea, but after a quick look, its seems there is no output of path. thanks for the alternative, never used `iosnoop`.

Comment: Yup that's why I didn't offer it as an answer.

Comment: Have you looked into using Linux auditing to solve your need?

Comment: @AndrewHenle can you be more specific? such as the `inotify` set of tools? I can't use anything that would need to walk the filesystem, the hierarchy is very complex.

Comment: @son_of_fire - Look here:  http://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/  The answer posted below shows one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux's [auditd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) can get the information for points 1 and 2.

Assuming you are running RHEL/CentOS 6 and have an nfs share mounted as `/mnt/nfs/foo`:

```
$ tree /mnt/nfs/foo
/mnt/nfs/foo
|-- a
|   `-- foo
|-- b
    `-- bar
```

You will need to define the following rules in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`:

```
# Delete existing rules
-D
# Set buffer size
-b 320
# Log read and write operations
-w /mnt/nfs/foo -p r -k read -k nfs
-w /mnt/nfs/foo -p w -k write -k nfs
```

And then reload the `auditd` service with `/etc/init.d/auditd reload`.

Once that is done you can use `ausearch` and `aureport` to read the event logs generated by `auditd`:

```
$ cat /mnt/nfs/foo/a/foo
$ echo 'test' > /mnt/nfs/foo/b/bar
$ ausearch -k nfs | aureport -f
File Report
===============================================
# date time file syscall success exe auid event
===============================================
1. 07/15/2015 11:39:04 /mnt/nfs/foo/a/foo 2 yes /bin/cat 500 59
2. 07/15/2015 11:39:05 /mnt/nfs/foo/b/bar 2 yes /bin/bash 500 60
```

One caveat that it will only be able to collect the information from the client side. If your client is un-trusted you can not use this method to safely determine what they are accessing over nfs.

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but it is very verbose. It also shows all executions in the specified folder (such as /bin/ls or /bin/bash). Is there a way to decrease verbosity? Also, I don't see how to distinguish reads from writes, is it the last column? (respectively numbers 59/60 in your example)

Comment: When using `-k nfs` as an argument to ausearch it's matching the `-k nfs` definition in `/etc/audit/audit.rules`. The keys `read` and `write` are also defined so you could also do `ausearch -k read` or `ausearch -k write` to see just reads or just writes. In terms of verbosity I'd suggest piping through `awk` to just get the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/).

Here is a slightly modified [example](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/keyword-index.html#FILE) showing opens, reads and writes every 100ms:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

global fileread, filewrite

probe syscall.open.return {
    if ($return != -1) {
        printf("open, %s, %d/%d\n", user_string($filename), pid(), $return)
    }
}

probe syscall.read.return {
    p = pid()
    fd = $fd
    bytes = $return
    if (bytes > 0)
        fileread[p, fd] += bytes
}

probe syscall.write.return {
    p = pid()
    fd = $fd
    bytes = $return
    if (bytes > 0)
        filewrite[p, fd] += bytes
}

probe timer.ms(100) {
    foreach (v = [p,fd] in fileread) {
        printf("read, %d, %d/%d\n", v, p, fd)
    }                                                                                                                                                                                          
    delete fileread                                                                                                                                                                            
    foreach (v = [p,fd] in filewrite) {                                                                                                                                                        
        printf("write, %d, %d/%d\n", v, p, fd)                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                          
    delete filewrite                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

The format of output lines is:

- open, (pathname), (pid)/(fd)
- read, (bytes), (pid)/(fd)
- write, (bytes), (pid)/(fd)

Comment: Providing a link to a possible solution is great but you should also include the relevant part here.