# Trace access to a directory tree

Tags: linux, inotify

## Situation

I have a directory `/home/foo` on a server, and I guess that it is not needed any more.

Unfortunately nobody can tell me if this directory is still needed.

## Goal

If this directory is still needed, I want to know which process accesses it.

## Current Strategy

Watch all file opens below this directory.

## Why not inotify

Unfortunately the directory contains a lot of sub-directories, that's why I don't want to use inotify.

- 1604508 files
- 287253 sub-directories

## Question

How can I watch all file opens below a directory (recursive) tree? I want to know which process access it.

## Environment

- `/home` is an ext4 filesystem.
- SuSE Linux 12.3. Kernel: 3.7.10

## Not duplicate

My question is not a duplicate of [Is it possible to find out what program or script created a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file) since ....:

- I can't use inotify since the directory tree contains too many sub directories.
- I can't use loggedfs: I can't change the file system type of this directory.

## Bounty

There are already two good answers. But I am curious, maybe there are other ways: Bounty of 50 :-)

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: @EightBitTony SuSE. I updated the question.

Comment: SUSE has auditd, so my answer should work.

Comment: Why couldn't you make a filesystem of `/home/foo`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos `/home/foo` is already a filesystem. I guess you mean "why couldn't you change the filesystem type?". Right?

Comment: No. You indicated this detail for `/home` not for `/home/foo`. My idea was to suggest you to make an independant FS of `/home/foo` and to track any `/dev/rdiskn` raw device access.

Comment: You can always take the low-tech approach of removing the directory tree (after backing up the fs, of course) and seeing who or what complains. :)

Comment: @jayhendren the directory tree is  huge, and in the backup. I could do a remove and restore, but this would cause a lot of IO which would impact the service of this machine. That's why I want a solution without changing the filesystem type. Do you understand my concerns? If not, please ask :-)

Comment: [SystemTap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemTap) can be used to monitor opening files like described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216851/123888)...you can delete all but the `syscall.open.return` probe (as you do not need to monitor reads and writes)...good luck!

Comment: [This one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6080/123888) is interesting as well...

Comment: @jayhendren I fully support the BOFH method of "removing it and seeing who complains".

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use `auditd` (although it depends on your Linux distribution having it available).

The `auditctl` command is used to configure auditing, and the man page should describe how to achieve what you need.

Something like,

`auditctl -w /home/foo -p war -k foo-watch`

You can then search the audit log later using,

`ausearch -k foo-watch`

An example of doing this on SUSE can be [found here](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/singlehtml/audit_quickstart/audit_quickstart.html).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's enabled in SuSE, but the **fanotify** api watches an entire filesystem. There is even a simple utility [fatrace](https://launchpad.net/fatrace) that will show you each file being opened, read, written, closed. Example

```
$ cd; sudo fatrace -f O -c 
tail(1500): CO /home/meuh/dot/privoxy/logs/160426
ls(28599): O /home/meuh
bash(2075): O /home/meuh/dot/bashhistory.xt-right
```

The `-f O` is just to trace opens, and `-c` to just trace the entire filesystem which holds the current working directory. You can optionally get a timestamp too.

Comment: fatrace is available for openSUSE >13.1, not before, according to http://software.opensuse.org/package/fatrace?search_term=fatrace (expand the lists to find there's no package for 12.3).

Comment: I hope we get a more recent Linux soon :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can see several ways:

- if your filesystem containing /home/foo is mounted with the atime (or equivalent for your filesystem's type), you can then use `find /home/foo -atime +10 -ls` to see if any of its files has been accessed in less than 11 days
- or if you prefer to "poke" and see if **right now** something is accessed under this directory : `lsof | grep /home/foo` should give you some clue (to test:  `cd /home/foo ; lsof | grep /home/foo` : should at least outputs your shell's pid, as it now has its cwd (current working directory) under that path...)

( note: I can't test both right now, no linux at hand... but I think both should work )